# How to edit the response sent back to jquery after successful form submit in Django

Tags: jquery, django, form-submit

I have this code

`(r'^book/create/$', create_update.create_object, book_model)`

`book_model = {'model' : Book, "template_name" : "app/generic_form.html",}`

I also have `get_absolute_url(self)` so that after creating new row it gets redirected to

`/books/lists`

The form is working fine.

Now I have used jquery Form plugin to submit the form. Now when i submit the form then data gets inserted via Ajax but don't get anything back.

I think when forms finishes post then it will redirect or `/books/list` so that can be the reason why i don't get any data back to jquery.

Now i want that form should work as it is but when i use jquery then i want to display something data added succesfuly but  i don't know how to do that as i am using generic views

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This view needs to be reached from a normal submit and from an ajax one

1) Add a parameter to the called url for let understand the view if is an ajax call or not, you can also use an hidden field set ad "ajax"

2) If the view found the parameter "ajax" it give you back a message or an error if there is one, otherwise it perform the redirect.

Consider also to use two different urls for the same view

```
book/create/(?P<type>[a-z])/

book/create/standard/$ """do redirect after submit"""
book/create/ajax/$ """return httpresponse"""
```

Answer (score 2):

Add a `success` parameter to the plugin call:

```
$('#your_form').ajaxForm({
  success: function(response){
    alert("Data added successfully");
  }
});
```

Hope this helps. Cheers

Comment: But what will happen with data output by generic view  which is there after successfully submitted the form.

Comment: You have the data output in the `response` parameter of the `success` handler

Comment: The problem that he say that the page perform a redirect, than in the response you will have the whole html page.